# How to add double quotes around data in tables using Calc

Tags: csv, spreadsheet, libreoffice-calc, openoffice-calc

I am trying to load my data into a CRM, but am having a lot of trouble. The data simply wont load at the same time, but all the files work fine individually. Support advised that I make sure I'm using double quotes. This is a decent sized list and I can't go through all the tables to add double quotes. Is there an easy way to add double quotes around the data in each table?

Comment: Do any of the cells contain tab indentations or carriage returns? If not, my own fix would be to copy the entire data set to a robust text editor (like Notepad++ or Text Wrangler), and replace every instance of \t and \n (tab and new line) with "\t" and "\n", thereby adding a double quote to the beginning and end of every cell (excluding the very first cell). Of course, this method is clunky, but slightly better than having to plug characters into each cell individually.

Comment: Calc should be using double-quotes when you save as CSV by default - if not, there should be an option to configure it. You can verify this by viewing the file in a text editor (e.g.: Notepad) instead of Calc.

Comment: There are no double quotes when I save them in Calc. It uses just the single comma: test,test,test,test,test,test,,,,. They provided me with a sample CSV using the double quotes, but Calc seems to remove them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to select "Quoted field as text" when opening the CSV.

Answer (score 0):

Calc was messing with my csv files because I wasn't paying close enough attention to the import options.  For example, I had a csv file with 2 columns: **id** and **text**.  The **text** column needed to be double quoted text, so I told Calc this column was Text and checked the "Format quoted field as text" option as shown below.  When I did this, the text in this field was double quoted.

[image]